# How do I convert a num::Rational to a decimal number?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use the external library [num](http://doc.rust-lang.org/num/num/index.html) with the goal to convert fractions to arbitrarily long decimal points, however, by reading the docs, I cannot find some clarifying example to convert a fraction to a decimal number. Anyone know how?

Comment: Might be important to note that the entire crate `num` has been deprecated from rust in 1.0 for some odd reason. Anyone know why?

Comment: Probably not truly deprecated, but [extracted to a library not in the standard library](https://github.com/rust-lang/num). The one in the standard library is deprecated so you start using the external library. This is a common pattern right now.

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0369-num-reform.md

Answer (score 1):

I think that printing out *arbitrary precision decimals* is simply a hard problem. I don't see that [the GNU Multiple Precision (GMP)
Arithmetic Library](https://gmplib.org/manual/Rational-Number-Functions.html#Rational-Number-Functions) supports this functionality. While Rust isn't built on top of GMP, if GMP doesn't have it I wouldn't expect Rust to have it.

The best you may be able to do is divide the numerator by the denominator yourself...